# Mongo Tailable Cursor { Error: No More Documents in Tailed Cursor }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cursor, capped-collections

When I try to run my code it shows "MongoError: No More Documents in Tailed Cursor".

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
const dataSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    name: Number,
    timestamp: Number
}, { capped: 5000000 });
const CappedData = mongoose.model('cappedData', dataSchema);
const dataCursor = CappedData.find({}).tailable(true, {awaitData: true}).cursor();
dataCursor.on('data', doc => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Tailable on an empty capped collection will cause this error, make sure the collection is not empty (Tested it and it works)